# Mongojack: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId

Tags: json, mongodb, pojo, mongojack

## Goal

I am trying to push some data to a mongo db using [mongojack](https://mongojack.org).
I expect the result to be something like this in the db:

```
{
 "_id": "840617013772681266",
 "messageCount": 69420,
 "seedCount": 18,
 "prefix": "f!",
 "language": "en"
}
```

## Problem

Instead, I get this error in my console.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [840617013772681266]
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.parseHexString(ObjectId.java:390)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:193)
    at org.mongojack.internal.ObjectIdSerializer.serialiseObject(ObjectIdSerializer.java:66)
    at org.mongojack.internal.ObjectIdSerializer.serialize(ObjectIdSerializer.java:49)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)
    ... 59 more
```

## Code

This is the code that gets called when I try to create a new Guild in the db:

```
    public static Guild getGuild(String id) throws ExecutionException {
        return cache.get(id);
    }
```

`cache` is the following (load get executed):

```
    private static LoadingCache<String, Guild> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<>() {
                        @Override
                        public Guild load(@NotNull String id) {
                            return findGuild(id).orElseGet(() -> new Guild(id, "f!"));
                        }
                    });
```

The `findGuild` method that gets called first:

```
    public static Optional<Guild> findGuild(String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(guildCollection.find()
                .filter(Filters.eq("_id", id)).first());
    }
```

And finally the `Guild` document.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Guild implements Model {

    public Guild(String id, String prefix) {
        this.id = id;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public Guild() {
    }

    private String id;

    /*
    If a Discord guild sent 1,000,000,000 messages per second,
    it would take roughly 292471 years to reach the long primitive limit.
     */
    private long messageCount;

    private long seedCount;

    // The default language is specified in BotValues.java's bot.yaml.
    private String language;

    private String prefix;

    @ObjectId
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ObjectId
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

## What I've tried

I've tried multiple things, such as doing `Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(id))` truth is I don't understand the error completely and after seeing [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) I'm left with more questions than answers.

Comment: Please forward me any questions regarding code I might not be showing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectId is a 12-byte value that is commonly represented as a sequence of 24 hex digits. It is not an integer.

You can either create ObjectId values using the appropriate ObjectId constructor or parse a 24-hex-digit string. You appear to be trying to perform an integer conversion to ObjectId which generally isn't a supported operation.

You can technically convert the integer `840617013772681266` to an ObjectId by zero-padding it to 12 bytes, but standard MongoDB driver tooling doesn't do that for you and considers this invalid input (either as an integer or as a string) for conversion to ObjectId.

Example in Ruby:

```rb
irb(main):011:0> (v = '%x' % 840617013772681266) + '0' * (24 - v.length)
=> "baa78b862120032000000000"
```

Note that while the resulting value would be parseable as an ObjectId, it isn't constructed following the ObjectId rules and thus the value cannot be sensibly decomposed into the ObjectId components (machine id, counter and a random value).

Comment: The id is a string though, and I've tried Long.toHexString. I have also tried to use the ObjectId constructor but to no avail. I'm missing something in your answer 100%.

Comment: "840617013772681266" is not convertable to an objectid using standard driver tooling regardless of whether it's stored in a string or an integer.

Comment: How do you recommend I go on doing the zero-padding method you mentioned in your answer?